# Send two email ids in CC

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am obtaining two email id's from database by a query. Both stored in a single variable. I want to send email to these two addresses by PHPMailer keeping them in cc. Currently only one email is being selected and passed in cc. Can I know where am I going wrong. My code here,

```
  $get_cc_email_id_sql=mysql_query("select * from tbl_name where column_name IN(13,5)");
          $user_email_cc='';
          while ($get_data_cc=mysql_fetch_array($get_cc_email_id_sql))
          {

           $user_email_cc=$get_data_cc['email'];

          } 
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$subject = "Mail";  
$content ="XYZ";
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->Port     = 465;  
$mail->Username = "xyz@xyz.com";   // Changed username and password from 
$mail->Password = "xyz";
$mail->Host     = "ssl://smtp.xyz.com";
$mail->Mailer   = "smtp";
$mail->SetFrom("xyz@xyz.com", "XYZ");
$mail->AddAddress(abc@abc.com);
$mail->AddCC($user_email_cc);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->WordWrap   = 80;
$mail->MsgHTML($content);
$mail->IsHTML(true);  
if(!$mail->Send()) 
    echo "Problem sending mail.";   
else      
  echo "Mail Sent";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `$user_email_cc` as array then it will store you both email a `0 and 1` position

```
$user_email_cc=array();
          while ($get_data_cc=mysql_fetch_array($get_cc_email_id_sql))
          {

           $user_email_cc[] =$get_data_cc['email'];

          }
```

**New Code**

```
$get_cc_email_id_sql=mysql_query("select * from tbl_name where column_name IN(13,5)");
         $user_email_cc=array();
          while ($get_data_cc=mysql_fetch_array($get_cc_email_id_sql))
          {

           $user_email_cc[] =$get_data_cc['email'];

          } 
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$subject = "Mail";  
$content ="XYZ";
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->Port     = 465;  
$mail->Username = "xyz@xyz.com";   // Changed username and password from 
$mail->Password = "xyz";
$mail->Host     = "ssl://smtp.xyz.com";
$mail->Mailer   = "smtp";
$mail->SetFrom("xyz@xyz.com", "XYZ");
foreach($user_email_cc as $email_cc){
 $mail->AddCC($email_cc);
}
$mail->AddAddress(abc@abc.com);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->WordWrap   = 80;
$mail->MsgHTML($content);
$mail->IsHTML(true);  
if(!$mail->Send()) 
    echo "Problem sending mail.";   
else      
  echo "Mail Sent";
```

Comment: Thanks for your concern. May I know how can I use this in Addcc

Comment: you can pass comma separated value in in Addcc

Comment: Can you please rewrite that part of Addcc for using it. I am not getting it clear. Thanks

Comment: check now please

Answer (score 2):

use this code

```
$mail->AddCC('person1@domain.com', 'Person One');
$mail->AddCC('person2@domain.com', 'Person Two');
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you call `$mail->AddCC(...)` multiple times, just like `$mail->AddAddress(...)`?